# Unable to insert into table in hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create new table and join with ManyToOne relation with my existing table
below is my implementation
New table

```
    @Entity(name="request_city_id")
    @Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraints{columnNames={"request_id","cityId"})})
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @FieldDefault(level=AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    public class RequestCityId{

            @GenratedValue(strategy=SEQUENCE, generator="seq_req_city_id")
            @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_req_city_id", allocationSize=1)
            @Column(name="rc_id") 
            @Id
            long id;

            @ManyToOne
            @JoinColumn(name="request_id")
            Request request;
            String cityId;
            String status
    }
```

Existing table

```
        @Entity(name="request")
        @Data
        @NoArgsConstructor
        @FieldDefault(level=AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
        public class Request{
            String frequency
            @GenratedValue(strategy=SEQUENCE, generator="seq_req_d")
            @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_req_id", allocationSize=1)
            @Column(name="request_id") 
            @Id
            long id;

            @OneToMany(cascade={ PERSIST, MERGE}, mappedBy="request", fetch=EAGER)
            Set<RequestCityId> requestCityIds;
 
    }
```

but when I am trying to insert into my new table I see my hibernate query gets stuck and just gets timed out after sometime, I am not sure what I am doing wrong here? If I just kep cascade type MERGE then getting
*Hibernate Error: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session*

Answer (score 0):

First you should create an getters and setters method to each entity.

[Request Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPLhn.png)
[Request City Id Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXkOM.png)

this code creates the tables and also saves the data into the table.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Data in entity classes in not recommended because it may cause some problems with jpa as mentioned [here](https://www.jpa-buddy.com/blog/lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong/).

Comment: but we were using it before hand, we had multiple OneToMany join before as well in same class it is working fine